# Create simple generic Automapper in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I am attempting to create a generic auto mapper, I want to map data from a dto to a database entity.

The error I am getting is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'QuestionEntity'

Kindly assist - I'm using AutoMapper v12.0.0.

This is my code:

```
public class MappingService: IMappingService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MappingService()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<object, object>();
            });

        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

This is the `Program` file and the setup in it:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

This is the usage:

```
var data = _mapperService.Map<QuestionEntity>(inputfromDto);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create such an generic AutoMapper. You have to be explicit about which source types can be mapped to which target types. Mostly you have multiple projects within your solution and each projects has its own types. You should create within each project a class derived from `Profile` and add your desired mappings. That's the intentation how AutoMapper works.

If you really like to make this *more magic*, probably you could create some kind of Attribute that you write on each desired type (e.g. `MapToAttribute(Type type)`), then use reflection to find all those marked types and create and add a profile at runtime. But this would only work for the most simple mappings. Whenever you have to define something with `.ForMember()` or similar, you have to take the route of writing down a profile.

At the beginning I thought such a generic mapper would be great too. But taking the road of writing down profiles really saved me a lot of times, cause I accidentially used the wrong type in the `.Map()` call. When a mapping is missing, AutoMapper is very descriptive about what is missing (just don't forget to look deeper for some inner exception) and it can be easily added in the best case by a single line of code. But having the freedom to define more granular about property mapping, cause the names don't match exactly happens more often then you probably expect at the beginning. So better take the `Profiles` road and get used to it. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough information to go on, so I'm going to assume you have a QuestionDto class defined.  In that case, you would need to define a map between that dto type and your entity type.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<QuestionDto,QuestionEntity>();
});
```